# fopen 't' compatibility mode in php

Tags: php, fopen

It is said, that `fopen` can use `t` mode to convert `\n` to `\r\n`. So, questions:

**1)** How should i use `t` mode when i need to read and write (`r+`)? Should it be `r+t` or `rt+` or `tr+`? Same question for `b`, should i write `r+b` or how?

**2)** I've tried all variants on debian linux to convert file, that contains only `\n` to `\r\n` using magic mode `t` (wanna understand how it works). But it does not work. What am I doing wrong? When `t` mode works?

Here is my code:

```
// Write string with \n symbols
$h = fopen('test.file', 'wt');
fwrite($h, "test \ntest \ntest \n"); // I've checked, after file is being created
fclose($h);                          // \n symbols are not substituted to \r\n

// Open file, that contains rows only with \n symbols
$h = fopen('test.file', 'rt');
$data = fread($h, filesize('test.file'));
fclose($h);

// I want to see what's inside
$data = str_replace("\n", '[n]', $data);
$data = str_replace("\r", '[r]', $data);

// finally i have only \n symbols, \r symbols are not added
var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: http://php.net/fopen

> **Windows** offers a text-mode translation flag ('t') which will transparently translate \n to \r\n when working with the file. In contrast, you can also use 'b' to force binary mode, which will not translate your data. To use these flags, specify either 'b' or 't' as the last character of the mode parameter.

So no Linux. Also, according to the spec `r+t` or `r+b` would be correct (but only on Windows).

Comment: Hmm.. so, if developer expect his code to be run sometime under windows, he should use just b not to corrupt data, right?

I'll check how it works under windows, thx

Comment: P.S. Can you give a link to the spec please? (for `r+b` syntax)?

Comment: I linked it AND it's in the quote I posted.

Comment: I know where are docs for fopen function in php, but i can't see any examples, showing that `r+b` or `r+t` is correct syntax (excluding user's comments with negative rating)

Comment: > To use these flags, specify either 'b' or 't' as the **last** character of the mode parameter. --- So unless the doc lies, `r+t` and `r+b` are correct, again NOT ON LINUX.

Comment: I will read docs carefully. I will read docs carefully. I will read docs carefully. Thx!

Comment: It is worth noting that the `b` and `t` flags won't trigger a notice, warning or error on Linux, they will simply be ignored.