# Comment form in HTML & PHP not display

Tags: php, html, linux

i am very new with html/css too with php and my English is very poor..
so , my problem ... , i have this Codec from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0KwnPS5OhGI) . I have Three File , the First is **index.php**

```
<html> 
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"> 
</head> 

<body> 
<form action="" method="POST"> 
<label>Name: 
<input type="text" name="Name" class="Input" style="width: 225px" required> 
</label> 
<br><br> 
<label> Comment: <br> 
<textarea name="Comment" class="Input" style="width: 300px" required> </textarea> 
</label> 
<br><br> 
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Comment" class="Submit"> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html> 

<?php 

    if($_POST['Submit']){  



        $Name = $_POST['Name']; 
        $Comment = $_POST['Comment']; 


        #Get old comments 
        $old = fopen("comments.txt", "r+"); 
        $old_comments = fread($old, 1024); 


        #Delete everything, write down new and old comments 
        $write = fopen("comments.txt", "w+"); 
        $string = "<b>".$Name."</b><br>".$Comment."<br>\n".$old_comments; 
        fwrite($write, $string); 
        fclose($write); 
        fclose($old); 
    } 

        #Read comments 
        $read = fopen("comments.txt", "r+"); 
        echo "<br><br>Comments<hr>".fread($read, 1024); 
        fclose($read); 


?>
```

Than a style.css File and a empty with the  name comments.txt . This Files i have to a Computer (**computer A**) , with apache , start it with , **/etc/init.d/apache2 restart** .In another Computer (**computer B**) i write to Browser, *192.345.345.100/index.php* , in **Name** i write my name and in **Comment** , a comment.. ,what come nothing.... .Image from mine Browser [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzlYP.png) , can please anyone help me , Thanks !

The image from Computer **B** , in Browser write  *http://192.345.345.100/info.php*  ,info.php which i have to build  with `<?php  phpinfo();  ?>` .

**See stacktrace:**

[image]

Comment: I've never seen the `t` option for `fopen`. I'd just use `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`. They are much easier. A DB would be a better approach though.

Comment: The image looks like you don't have PHP installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! , sorry but i am very new , i don't understand with file_get_contents  , can you please give me a example ....

Comment: php.net is a great place to go for answers http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php Those will be for after you get the PHP running. They will replace your `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, and `fclose`.

Comment: From my computer A,  PHP -V :      PHP 7.2.2-1 (cli) (built: Feb 1 2018 15:19:04) ( NTS )

Comment: That is command line. Do you have if configured to run from your server software as well?

Comment: /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: That just restarts apache, do you have the module installed?

Comment: which module ??

Comment: PHP you need apache to know to run PHP.

Comment: i know .. so every time before server to use , i start apache... /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: @user3783243 ,You have Right , T don't belong to fopen.... i will to revise from mine Code.... but it have not affect to  display....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit new my comment... , i had two problem because PHP not display.... . **First** ,me messing some modules for PHP , **libapache2-mod-php7.0**..

**Seconds** ,i not had access right to my Website... , with **sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html** , i have this Right to give....
[image how the Website see with the Comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjOiX.png) , The Code remain identical...

@user3783243 , today i to red [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239731/fopen-t-compatibility-mode-in-php)  , how Understand , **t** convert \n to \r\n , it is **ONLY** for Windows user.. , Linux ignored it ... .

**\n** is used for Unix systems (including Linux, and OSX).

**\r\n** is mainly used on Windows.

**\r** is used on really old Macs.

from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824621/is-a-new-line-n-or-r-n) .

Comment: so you "found" the solution, "have to find" means its not solved yet